# Error while installing vertx (vertx run server.js)

Tags: javascript, servlets, vert.x

I have Mac and i am installing Vertx version 2.0.2-final
when i run vertx run server.js i get the following error :-

```
 org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: illegal character   
 (file:/Users/ICHI05/Documents/vertx/test/server.js#1)
```

Following is the server.js :-

```
var vertx = require('vertx');

vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(function(req) {
req.response.end("Hello World!");
}).listen(8080, 'localhost');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it.
TextEdit adds some formatting to it so i use vi editor now.

Comment: Cant use vscode?